# Nomes das Categorias não estão sendo apresentadas. object (1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-2.0

Alguém pode me ajudar a corrigir por que os nomes das categorias não estão sendo exibidos no meu console de administração?

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Cad_pref(models.Model):
    nomepref = models.CharField("Nome Prefeitura:", max_length=200)
    endpref = models.CharField("Endereço Prefeitura:", max_length=200)
    numpref = models.CharField("Número Prefeitura:", max_length=10)
    telpref = models.CharField("Telefone Prefeitura:", max_length=15)
    cnpjpref = models.CharField("CNPJ:", max_length=15)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou implementar o método `__str__` com o valor que deseja?

Comment: Me desculpa a ignorancia, pesquisei no site do Django e não vi sobre. Este painel é "padrão" dele?

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso amigo:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Cad_pref(models.Model):
nomepref = models.CharField("Nome Prefeitura:", max_length=200)
endpref = models.CharField("Endereço Prefeitura:", max_length=200)
numpref = models.CharField("Número Prefeitura:", max_length=10)
telpref = models.CharField("Telefone Prefeitura:", max_length=15)
cnpjpref = models.CharField("CNPJ:", max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nomepref
```

Answer (score 0):

Fabio, você pode escolher o nome que aparecerá para cada modelo do Django criado por você. 
basta implementar o metodo:

`def __str__(self):
        return self.name`

No seu caso ficaria:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Cad_pref(models.Model):
    nomepref = models.CharField("Nome Prefeitura:", max_length=200)
    endpref = models.CharField("Endereço Prefeitura:", max_length=200)
    numpref = models.CharField("Número Prefeitura:", max_length=10)
    telpref = models.CharField("Telefone Prefeitura:", max_length=15)
    cnpjpref = models.CharField("CNPJ:", max_length=15)

 def __str__(self):
        return self.nomepref #pondo aqui o nome que você quer que apareça em seu admin
```

Você pode ler mais sobre [aqui](https://djangobook.com/advanced-models/)